# Hide project name with nginx proxy

Tags: java, nginx, proxy, wildfly

I try to redirect the traffic from the nginx proxy (PROXY_IP) to the Wildfly instance (WILDFLY_IP). The java project is reachable with the url http://WILDFLY_IP:8080/PROJECT_NAME. I want to hide the project name, that the users can access http://PROXY_IP/ and see the same. The nginx proxy is also used to enforce HTTPS.

My config looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
    server {
            listen 443;
            server_name PROXY_IP;

            ssl_certificate            xxxx;
            ssl_certificate_key        xxxx;

            ssl on;
            ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
            ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.error.log;

            location / {
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                    proxy_pass              http://WILDFLY_IP:8080/PROJECT_NAME;
                    proxy_read_timeout  90;

                    proxy_redirect          http://WILDFLY_IP:8080/PROJECT_NAME                https://PROXY_IP;

            }

            location /PROJECT_NAME {
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                    proxy_pass              http://WILDFLY_IP:8080/PROJECT_NAME;
                    proxy_read_timeout  90;
                    proxy_redirect          http://WILDFLY_IP:8080/PROJECT_NAME                https://PROXY_IP;
            }

    }
```

The configuration forwards the traffic to the Wildfly instance and enforce https, but it redirects the user from http://PROXY_IP/ to https://PROXY_IP/PROJECT_NAME

Comment: Why not deploy your war file to `/` instead of trying to hack it via nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this with a rewrite.

```
location /PROJECT_NAME {
        ....
        rewrite /PROJECT_NAME/(.*) /$1 break;
        ....
}
```